# How to path source inline html in webview.ReactNative (Expo)?

Tags: react-native, expo

in my project has webview that redirects to a local HTML page.
All the links (css, js, images) inside HTML do not work when I do Publish(the Last option in Metro-Bundler) and build(expo build:android).
When I run local on Metro-Bundler it works great.

example

in app.js:

```
<WebView
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          source={Expo.Asset.fromModule(require('../../assets/index.html'))}
       />
```

in inex.html(the file in "assets" folder):

```
enter code here

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <title>title</title>
  <meta content="Webflow" name="generator">
  <link href="../css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="../css/webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                <video>
                    <source src="videos/Space2381.mp4#t=0.5" type="video/mp4">
                </video>

            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/abc.png" style="
                   width: 66%;
                 margin-left: 17%;
            " />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

(in assets have: index.html, images(folder with images file),videos(folder with videos file)

this in App.json:

```
"assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*",
      "assets/*"
    ],
```